# Write a Bash Command File for OpenFoam to periodically change an entry

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to use an OpenFOAM case called ConstVolt_0flow where I am advised to write a bash command-file that would periodically switch the entry in ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme from:

gradSchemes
{
default         Gauss linear;
}

to

gradSchemes
{
default         Gauss cubic;
}

The openFoam is v2.4. Because I don't have experience of writing anything linux-related, I can't tell if the code written by chatgpt is correct:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to the fvScheme file
fvSchemeFile="system/Air/fvScheme"

# Check the current scheme
currentScheme=$(grep -Po '(?<=default\s+Gauss\s+)\w+' "$fvSchemeFile")

# Switch the scheme
if [ "$currentScheme" == "linear" ]; then
    sed -i 's/default\s\+Gauss\s\+linear/default         Gauss cubic/' "$fvSchemeFile"
else
    sed -i 's/default\s\+Gauss\s\+cubic/default         Gauss linear/' "$fvSchemeFile"
fi

echo "Switched gradSchemes in $fvSchemeFile to Gauss $currentScheme"
```

This is the command-prompt window I am using (sorry for the windows-terminology):
[image]

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: As this seems to be pretty much a programming-related question not really specific for Ubuntu, you may want to raise the question in a forum designated to programming question, like e.g. StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simpler solution that just swaps two entire files:

1. Create `ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme` with the version of the file with `gradSchemes { default Gauss linear; }`
2. Create `ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme.new` with the version of the file with `gradSchemes { default Gauss cubic; }`
3. Create the file that does the swapping, `./doswap.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

cp 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme' 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme.tmp'
mv 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme.new' 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme'
mv 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme.tmp' 'ConstVolt_0flow/system/Air/fvScheme.new'

# Note: you may need to add a line here to restart your service
# However, if this "OpenFOAM" simulation software should not be restarted
# then it might be off topic for Ask Ubuntu

echo "Switched gradSchemes in fvScheme to other Gauss"
```

4. Create the `./looper.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  ./doswap.sh
  sleep 1m # This is the period. It is set to 1 minute currently. You can adjust it
  # Or better, use systemd or some daemon to call ./doswap.sh instead of this
done
```

5. `chmod +x doswap.sh looper.sh` (or right click properties, and set both files to executable)
6. Start everything by running `./looper.sh` in your terminal (or just double click it, but double clicking might not show you the terminal output)
7. Stop things by pressing CTRL+C

Comment: could you tell me what do you mean by start everything with ./looper.sh? And could you point out where is the swapping "period?"

Comment: "start everything with ./looper.sh" means to open terminal to that directory, then type `./looper.sh` in terminal, or whatever you named that file. The swapping period is on the "sleep 1m" line. I set it to sleep 1 minute, you can adjust it to anything, seconds, minutes, hours